# xamarin forms background color of top status bar android

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'am using XamarinForms and  I wanna know if I can set the backgroundColor using the configuration of the app.xaml, I'm using styles and themes that can be change at runtime, it is possible?

[image: top of the cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using styles and themes that can be change at runtime, it is possible?

If you want to change status bar background at runtime, I suggest you can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to change status bar background in Android platform.

Add this code to your Xamarin.Forms project(shared code project)

```
 public interface IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
{
    void SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color color);
   
}
```

Implement the interface on Android platform. don't forget to register the platform implementations.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeStatusbar))]
namespace FormsSample.Droid
{
public class ChangeStatusbar : IStatusBarPlatformSpecific
{
    
    public void SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        // The SetStatusBarcolor is new since API 21
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            var androidColor = color.AddLuminosity(-0.1).ToAndroid();
            //Just use the plugin
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity.Window.SetStatusBarColor(androidColor);             
        }
        else
        {
            // Here you will just have to set your 
            // color in styles.xml file as shown below.
        }
    }     
}
}
```

Now, you can change status bar background by calling the Get method to resolve the IStatusBarPlatformSpecific interface

```
 private void btn1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var statusbar = DependencyService.Get<IStatusBarPlatformSpecific>();
        statusbar.SetStatusBarColor(Color.Green);
    }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The status bar should go the same colour as the navigation bar. You can set that to anything you like. I use styles to set this in a ContentPage as follows.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        (this.Parent as NavigationPage).Style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["NavBarColour"];
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```

];

Comment: Where do you write that code?  
I am Using Xamarin 5, mvvm with prism

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that bit. I put it in the OnAppearing event. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: but you did that in every form?   I don't use codebehind because the MVVM pattern :)

Comment: You only need to do it if you want it to change. So you could put it in your main page and nowhere else. I have several pages that are colour-coded to help navigation so they each set their own nav bar's colour. This is just the way I do it. I ended up breaking out of the MVVM pattern because the nature of my app made it more confusing than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For Android modify Resources/Values/Styles.xml file as

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#ffffff</item>
  </style>
```